# Regular Expression that doesn't match continuing strings but can be part of another string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following strings:

```
inputs.test=al
inputs.test=ally^inputs.test=alNOTinputs.test=altogether
inputs.test=ally^inputs.test=alwaysNOTinputs.test=al
inputs.test=alORinputs.test=al^inputs.test=ally^ORinputs.test=al
inputs.test<=alORinputs.test!=alORinputs.test>=al^inputs.test!=ally
```

I'd like to replace all instances of the string `inputs.test[= or != or <= or >= or NOT]al` with `inputs.test[= or != or <= or >= or NOT]FIXED`

All while ignoring substrings after the operator (in this example, always, ally, altogether should be left alone).

```
inputs.test=FIXED
inputs.test=ally^inputs.test=FIXEDNOTinputs.test=altogether
inputs.test=ally^inputs.test=alwaysNOTinputs.test=FIXED
inputs.test=FIXEDORinputs.test=FIXED^inputs.test=ally^ORinputs.test=FIXED
inputs.test<=FIXEDORinputs.test!=FIXEDORinputs.test>=FIXED^inputs.test!=ally
```

This may be too complicated to solve with just Regex, just wondering if there is a way.

Comment: Note the below regex could use a word boundary as an alternative which would be more comprehensive `/(inputs\.test(?:[!<>]?=|NOT))al\b/g`

Answer (score 2):

A little factoring and well placed assertion after the 'al' would make
this regex work.
Just replace with `$1FIXED`

```
/(inputs\.test(?:[!<>]?=|NOT))al(?!ly|together|ways)/g
```

https://regex101.com/r/CDSYuR/1

```
 (                             # (1 start)
    inputs \. test   
    (?:
       [!<>]? =
     | NOT
    )
 )                             # (1 end)
 al
 (?! ly | together | ways )
```